# Using Objects in Method

Tags: java, object

I am trying to use a menu system that can delete a customer from my array myHotel[], this is built from an object.

```
if(menu.charAt(0) == 'D')deleteCustomer(myHotel[]);
```

...

```
public void deleteCustomer(String myHotel[]){
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please Enter Room Number to Delete Customer");
         roomNum=input.nextInt();
         myHotel[roomNum].setName("e");
    }
```

I get the errors, cannot find symbol?

Here is the Full Code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int roomNum=0;
        Room[] myHotel = new Room[10];
        for (int x =0; x<10; x++){
           myHotel[x] = new Room(); 
        }

        String roomName;

        String menu;
        do { 

        System.out.println("Please Select an Option from the Menu:");
        System.out.println("Enter V to View all Rooms");
        System.out.println("Enter A to Add Customer to Room");
        System.out.println("Enter D to Delete Customer from Room");
        System.out.println("Enter Q to Quit");
        menu=input.next();
        //if(menu.charAt(0) == 'V')viewAllRooms(); 
        //if(menu.charAt(0) == 'A')addCustomer(); 
        if(menu.charAt(0) == 'D')deleteCustomer(myHotel[]);
        } while (menu.charAt(0) != 'Q');

            while (roomNum < 10) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++ )
             if (myHotel[x].getName().equals("e"))System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");

            System.out.println("Enter room number (0-9) or 10 to stop:");
            roomNum = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter name for room " + roomNum + " :");
            roomName = input.next();
            myHotel[roomNum].setName(roomName);

             for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                //System.out.println("room " + x + " occupied by " + myHotel[x].mainName);
                System.out.println("room " + x + " occupied by " + myHotel[x].getName());
            }
        }
    }
     public void deleteCustomer(String myHotelRef){
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please Enter Room Number to Delete Customer");
         int deleteRoom=input.nextInt();
         myHotelRef[deleteRoom].setName("e");
    }

     }
```

Comment: which symbol is giving you this error?

Comment: can not find symbol means you may have not declared your `method` or some `field`. Check if every `class` is `imported`.

Answer (score 5):

You get multiple errors. What is `myHotel[]`? `roomNum` is not defined, etc.

Please use your compiler.

Answer (score 3):

First you need declare `myHotel` array and pass it with out `[]`.

```
deleteCustomer(myHotel);
```

Second, there is not such a method `setName(String name)` in String class

```
myHotel[roomNum].setName("e");// no such a method
```

Third, you need to declare the `roomNum` variable like:

```
int roomNum = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: `roomNum` should be `int roomNum` since it appears to be an array index variable. *(also ignore previous messages if you saw them. Lousy phone.)*

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you've included `[]` in your call to `deleteCustomer`. It *should* be:

```
if (menu.charAt(0) == 'D') {
    deleteCustomer(myHotel);
}
```

When you reference an array object as a whole you don't include square brackets. Square brackets are for the declaration, initialisation and for accessing individual elements within the array.

I'd also recommend that you get into the habit of always using curly braces with your `if`, `for` and `while` constructs, as not including them is often the cause of bugs. It also makes it easier to read when you come back to it, and you're clearly indicating to others what should be part of the loop and what shouldn't.